# Combinatorics in $\lambda \phi^4$ theory and critical exponents

Tags: statistical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, conventions, ising-model, critical-phenomena

I am trying to understand critical phenomena from the perspective of Statistical Mechanics.

The interacting term in the $\lambda \phi^4$ scalar theory is usually (but not always) multiplied by $\frac{1}{4!}$. I have understood that this factor is useful for keeping track of the symmetry factors of different Feynman Diagrams (since symmetry factors partially simplify).

Is this multiplying factor arbitrary? I suppose that it cannot alter the critical exponents. However, the symmetry factors of Feynman Diagrams are crucial for accurately calculating critical exponents. Is there a straightforward way to see that the $\frac{1}{4!}$ factor has no significant effect (at least in computing critical exponents)?

Comment: Briefly speaking, normalizing the coupling constant as $\frac{\lambda}{4!}$ is merely a convention that doesn't affect the critical exponents.

Comment: Is there a simple way to see this? Maybe showing that the critical exponents are not affected?